# Length of location sequence (given as a string) in R

Tags: regex, r, count

I have a list of geolocation sequences. Each element of my list is of the form :

```
> "[[1.2,2.2],[-1.12,3.45],[12.311,-1.34],[-12.32,33.333]]"
```

I would like to be able to get the length of the sequence (4 in the example above). Could you please help me? I've tried to use regular expressions but I couldn't succeed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` of your list?

Comment: You could count how often ],[ appears + one.

Answer (score 1):

As a few folks suggested in the comments, you can count the # of times a specific character appears in your sequences. This assumes the data are well formed and consistent. For example:

```
library(stringr)
x <- "[[1.2,2.2],[-1.12,3.45],[12.311,-1.34],[-12.32,33.333]]"
str_count(x, "\\[") - 1 #subtract 1 since there are two opening [
```

yields:

```
> str_count(x, "\\[") - 1
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to load a library

```
str <- "[[1.2,2.2],[-1.12,3.45],[12.311,-1.34],[-12.32,33.333]]"
nchar(str)-nchar(gsub("\\]", "", str))-1
```

Comment: Alternative base solution: `length(gregexpr("\\[\\[|\\[",x)[[1]])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\[[^[]
```

And then count the matches.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE7yT3/1)

In R:

```
> x <- "[[1.2,2.2],[-1.12,3.45],[12.311,-1.34],[-12.32,33.333]]"
> length(gregexpr("\\[[^\\[]",x)[[1]])
[1] 4
```

Comment: Since the structure is known, you could just use `\[` and then subtract 1 from the final answer.  I'm not sure how much faster this makes it.